# Python zip all files in directory script failed

Tags: python

I want to write a very simple script with python that will zip all file in a folder. This is what i have until now:

```
import os
import zipfile
zfName = 'simonsZip.zip'
foo = zipfile.ZipFile(zfName, 'w')
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        print (os.path.join(dirname,filename))
        foo.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    foo.close()
```

When i `sudo python script.py` the script runs, but never ends, while producing an enormous zip file.

Any ideas?

Comment: os.walk('.') will go through every subdir in current path.  So that might be much more than you want.

Comment: Is the "foo.close()" correctly indented?

Comment: 1. Is `foo.close()` indented right above?  2. Should you filter out zfName from your list of files to zip?  3. When you say never ends... do you continually get output from your print statement?

Comment: Print works, i am getting output. As for zfName, yes you are right i should filter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a recursion. since the zip you created is listed in the files.
You're writing the zip inside the zip inside the zip inside the zip and so on.

Comment: yeap, having the zip file inside the folder that i want to zip was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this might become handy for you if you are running `linux` or `osx`.

```
from subprocess import call

zfName = 'simonsZip'
fnames = '*' #all files
call(["zip","-R", zfName, fnames])
```

this just zip all the files in the current directory recursively(`-R`).